FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed). when using Firebase and Expo Go
I am trying to use Firebase Web in a react native app. I am using Expo GO in development. When I am running createUserWithEmailAndPassword I get this error: [FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/network-request-failed).]
I have tried setting the Emulator Host, resetting the session, change network. No luck.
Firebase initialization code is below:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig";
import { initializeAuth, getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

// Authentication

export const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
export const db = getFirestore(app)

const auth = initializeAuth(app, {
    persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage)
})

